# Place filter in another component

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to use the Angular 2 material Data table module 
(https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) for creating a table but i need the filter used on example to be used inside another component and i don't fully understand how to do so. I don't understand how `@ViewChild('filter') filter: ElementRef;` works either and the docs don't seems to be very clear how it works.

Comment: You need to include your example's code so we know what you're talking about next year when that link goes dead: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your filter to another file, include and use it like this (I didn't test it, but it should work. Your filter code should go instead of `"Code for filter"` string, I guess, that you need a function at that place):

**filter.ts:**

```
export const Filter = "Code for filter";
```

**example.ts:**

```
/* other imports */
import { Filter } from 'path/to/filter.ts';

@Component({
  ...
})

export class ExampleComponent {
  constructor(
    private filter: Filter
  ) {}
}
```

**example.html:**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filter">
...
</div>
```